# error: use of undeclared identifier 'vmaxq_f16'

Tags: android, android-ndk, simd, intrinsics, neon

I get this error whenever I try to use the NEON 16-bit float intrinsics.
I do not face any issues with other data types intrinsics.

Isn't it possible to use NEON 16-bit float intrinsics on Android?

My code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <arm_fp16.h>
#include <arm_neon.h>

void useSIMD_f16() {
    float16_t zero = 0;
    float16x8_t zero_f16x8 = vld1q_dup_f16(&zero);
    float16_t one = 1;
    float16x8_t one_f16x8 = vld1q_dup_f16(&one);
    float16x8_t max = vmaxq_f16(zero_f16x8, one_f16x8);
}
```

Error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
> Error while executing process /home/raed/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /home/raed/AndroidStudioProjects/SIMD/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a native-lib}
> ninja: Entering directory `/home/raed/AndroidStudioProjects/SIMD/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a'
> [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o
> FAILED: CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o
> /home/raed/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++ --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi23 --gcc-toolchain=/home/raed/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/raed/Android/Sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot  -Dnative_lib_EXPORTS  -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o -c /home/raed/AndroidStudioProjects/SIMD/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
> /home/raed/AndroidStudioProjects/SIMD/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:7:30: error: use of undeclared identifier 'vld1q_dup_f16'
> float16x8_t zero_f16x8 = vld1q_dup_f16(&zero);
> ^
> /home/raed/AndroidStudioProjects/SIMD/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:9:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'vld1q_dup_f16'
> float16x8_t one_f16x8 = vld1q_dup_f16(&one);
> ^
> /home/raed/AndroidStudioProjects/SIMD/app/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp:10:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'vmaxq_f16'
> float16x8_t max = vmaxq_f16(zero_f16x8, one_f16x8);
> ^
> 3 errors generated.
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Half-precision floating point isn't available on all Arm targets.  Check whether the `__ARM_FEATURE_FP16_VECTOR_ARITHMETIC` macro is defined to determine whether the functions are available.

> Isn't it possible to use NEON 16-bit float intrinsics on Android?

It's not really an Android thing; some Android devices will support it, others won't. It depends on the CPU.

Comment: One of the nice things about ARM64 (a.k.a. AArch64) v8 is that it includes VFPv4, ARM-NEON, and half-precision support that was an optional extension in older chips--it also means ARM-NEON supports a real divide operator too. If you are targeting older ARM chips, you have to deal with the fact that it may or may not be supported in hardware.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn while true for the Half-Precision extend/narrow operations, `vmaxq_f16` is only available to cores implementing the Armv8.2-A Half-Precision Floating point extensions. @nemequ; for the vector operations (which `vmaxq_f16` would be) you need to check `__ARM_FEATURE_FP16_VECTOR_ARITHMETIC`. Of course, this is a compile time check, not a run-time check, so you'll need to be certain that the core you will end up executing on has the appropriate extension too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the appropriate compiler options and target architecture that support the half-precision floating-point arithmetic feature. Depending on the compiler you are using, the options may vary. Here are some examples:

For Clang for Arm, you can use `-march=armv8.2-a+fp16` to enable the feature macro and the _Float16 data type1.

For GCC for Arm, you can use `-mfpu=fp-armv8 -march=armv8.2-a+fp16` to enable the feature macro and the `_Float16` data type2.

For Android NDK, you can use `-march=armv8.2a+fp16` to enable the feature macro, but you may also need to check the `__ARM_FP16_FORMAT_IEEE` macro to determine the format of the half-precision values3.